# OpenSSH and OpenLDAP Configuration

Tags: 11.10, server, openssh, openldap

I have installed Ubuntu Server 11.10. I have setup LDAP with some users added.

Now i want to configure openssh to use this LDAP details to login to server. and once a user logs in each user should have their respective home directory.

Comment: Are you doing anything special with **SSH**, or do you just need **LDAP** to (further) manage your user's home directories, permissions, etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

Install the `libpam-ldap` and `libnss-ldap` packages.

While the packages are being installed, the setup process will ask you for the URI to your LDAP server, the DN of your LDAP search base, the LDAP version, etc, and then stores them in /etc/ldap.conf (or /etc/pam-ldap.conf and /etc/libnss-ldap.conf on older versions of Ubuntu).